# EWS Managed API Attachment - Properties of attchment to existing email are blank

Tags: exchangewebservices, attachment, rebex

I am converting an existing application that uses Rebex as email provider to use EWS Managed API.  My goal is to display a list of emails that have attachment via datagrid.  I have successfully done that.  However, when I select the email on the grid row to reply, all the attachment properties are null or have object is not reference.  The only property that has value is the Name.  For example, Content, ContentID, ContentLocation, ContentType are all blank.

Am I missing something?  Below is my code to create a list of attachment:

```
Private Sub AddParentAttachments()
   For Each att As Attachment In _parentMailMessage.Attachments
    Dim item As IMailAttachment = Nothing
    item = New EwsMailAttachment(att)
    Me.Add(item)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the code your using eg what EWS operations have you used ? The Attachment properties don't get returned when you use FindItems (only the hasAttachments property is). To get the Attachment properties you will need to use Load or LoadPropertiesForItems

Comment: This might be already handled by experimental EWS wrapper for Rebex Mail. It handles filling Mail Message properties automatically. See http://labs.rebex.net/ExchangeWebServices/ for details.